# EntitySqlException when using EntityConnection, EntityCommand and EntityDataReader

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting this error that I don't know how to solve when using EntityConnection. When using the ObjectContext I can set the property `DefaultContainerName` and it works but now I don't know what's causing the problem and how to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

The full error looks like this ->

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntitySqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'Animals' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple identifier, line 1, column 21.

My code looks like this and the exception is thrown when hitting cmd.ExecuteReader() ->

```
using (EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection("name=dbEntities"))
        {
            using (EntityCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT VALUE a FROM Animals AS a";
                conn.Open();
                using (EntityDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess | CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // code
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

The example is taken from this link -> http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx

EDIT. I use version 6

```
public partial class dbEntities : DbContext
{
    public dbEntities()
        : base("name=dbEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Names> Names { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Animals> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined Animals entity sets on your model ?

Comment: Myabe you must add `[YourContextEntitiesName].Animals` instead of jsut `Animals`

Comment: Hi, I use model first so I can't really alter with the model sets but I'll edit what it looks like.

Comment: Then use `dbEntities.Animals` in your Entity SQL instead of `Animals`after the `FROM` clause.

Comment: lol it works? If yes, i will add it as an answer then. To help those people who might forget to inclue the context name in the Entity SQL string.

Comment: do that, i'll promote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbContext`name is missing on your Entity SQL query. You must use `dbEntities.Animals` instead of just `Animals`. Finally your command text should look like this :

`SELECT VALUE a FROM dbEntities.Animals AS a`